# paypal and bitcoin? how do I accept them as payments from people

Tags: paypal, web, bitcoin

I'm trying to figure out how to accept XBT (Bitcoin) as a payment method on my site but I want to make sure I have every bit of info I need and that it is properly done. I'm using paypal as the means of collecting income from the site

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing it.

One way is to use a Bitcoin payment processor to accept Bitcoin payments, such as bitpay.com or coinbase.com.

These services work a lot like PayPal. When a customer wishes to make a Bitcoin payment, they would be taken to the payment processors website. They would then send the Bitcoin to the payment processor, and the amount would be credited to your account at the payment processor. You would then get paid by the payment processor, either in Bitcoin or sometimes in fiat currencies such as USD or Euro.

The advantage of going this route is that getting setup and maintaining this is fairly straight forward, the disadvantages are that the payment processor will charge you a fee, can terminate the service, and you must trust that they will actually pay you.

Another way is to accept Bitcoin payments directly with your own payment system.

One way to do this is you would download Bitcoin wallet software and create a Bitcoin wallet (see bitcoin.org for a list of wallet software), and store a list of some of the Bitcoin addresses (or preferably the wallets master public key) on your server. Whenever a customer wishes to make a Bitcoin payment, you would assign the order a Bitcoin address from the list, display it to the customer and use an API to check if the address has received any payments (it is highly advised to run your own node and use it's API to check for payments rather than use a 3rd party service). Once the payment is received in full and confirmed, then you would mark the order as paid and proceed with the order.

The advantages of this method are that you are receiving the payment directly and you have complete control over the payment system, you are guaranteed to receive the Bitcoin and there is no middleman that can prevent you from receiving payments and nobody charging you a fee (though you will still have to pay Bitcoin network transaction fees whenever you send a payment from your wallet). The disadvantages are that this system is difficult to setup and maintain, and if you wish to receive USD you will need to exchange the Bitcoins on a currency exchange yourself.

If you do not need to know whether a specific customer has paid you or not, such as if you are receiving donations, then you could simply create a Bitcoin wallet and put the address on your website. Or you could handle your payments manually by manually giving each customer a unique Bitcoin address and manually checking if they have paid or not.